# greedy_coloring code not working. Please show me why

Tags: python

My project have one file I cannot figure it out why its not running. It is greedy_coloring.py

Code:

```
import networkx as nx

from functions.global_properties import *
from functions.local_properties import *

G = nx.read_edgelist('test_graphs/G1.txt')

def greedy_proper_coloring(G):
    colored_verticies = {v: None for v in V(G)}
    colored_verticies[V(G)[0]] = 1
    for v in V(G):
        if colored_verticies[v] == None:
            N = neigbors(G, v)
            avoid_colors = [colored_verticies[w] for w in N]
            i = 1
            while colored_verticies[v] == None:
                if i not in avoid_colors:
                    colored_verticies[v] = i
                else:
                    i += 1
    return colored_verticies

print(greedy_proper_coloring(G))
```

This is the [link to my project](https://github.com/garciachavezj/nxGraphAlgorithms)

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "its not running".  Do you get an error?  Do you get unexpected output?

Answer (score 0):

1st issue: you are importing functions as a package so, please create an empty `__init__.py` file inside folder functions.

2nd issue: rename test_graphs folder to graph_library